# Continuous functions vanishing at infinity on a relatively compact space?

Tags: functional-analysis

The notion of 'vanishing at infinity' seems to suggest that for $f \in C_0(X)$, the underlying space $X$ is 'big'. However, formally, we only need $X$ to be locally compact. So I was wondering: if $X$ is relatively compact (in my use case, for example, an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$), does $C_0(X)$ simply consist of functions which vanish as we approach the boundary of $X$? And if so, does the name 'vanish at infinity' make any sense?

Comment: There are two meaningful notions: One requires functions to have compact support. The other, requires zero limit at infinity with 1-point compactification of $X$. Which one to use depends on your objective.

Comment: Yes but does it make sense to speak of "at infinity" when $C_0$ is bounded/relatively compact?

Comment: With the definitions I gave, $C_0$ is never bounded/ relatively compact.

Comment: As for $X$, saying "bounded" or "relatively compact" is the wrong thing to do, you should assume instead "locally compact."